# Invariant JS parameters are not clear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, error-handling, invariants

Why invariant function has this params:

```
function(condition, format, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
```

instead of:

```
function invariant(condition : any, format?: string, ...args : Array < any >) {
```

Can anyone clarify, because for me does not make any sense?

Updated:

This isthe link to the invariant library: https://github.com/zertosh/invariant/blob/master/invariant.js

The second function is written in ES6.

Comment: The second version isn't JS. Should this question have a "typescript" tag?

Comment: And a link to the source code.

Comment: The original author wrote in javascript, not typescript. Your question is a bit like asking why someone chooses to speak in English instead of French... I don't think there will be an answer unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: See below the links, if you understand this library and have insights. The comments comparing English and French are really for the second grade, and not for software engineers.

Comment: *"The second function is written in ES6."* - No it isn't. Anyway, are you trying to ask why the first version is limited to only six arguments in the message format string while the second appears to accept any number of arguments? Because you really don't make that clear, and you don't explain where the second version comes from. It would help if you could edit your question to explain why you expected the second version.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone clarify, because for me does not make any sense?

This is the choice the library author made. They only support `6` placeholders and hence only take 6 named args.

Comment: It looks that you guys are not familiars with invariant but still answer questions about it! 

Take a look at : https://github.com/zertosh/invariant/blob/master/invariant.js.flow

    /* @flow */
    
    declare module.exports: (
      condition: any,
      format?: string,
      ...args: Array<any>
    ) => void;


and 

https://github.com/zertosh/invariant/blob/master/invariant.js

    var invariant = function(condition, format, a, b, c, d, e, f) {